# Finding the longest (deepest) chain in a Tree and summing the TreeNodes?

Tags: python

Here I have some code I made which will give me the depth of a tree.

```
if isinstance(t, list):
        return 1 + max(depth(item) for item in t)
    else:
        return 0
```

The tree is of the form:

```
element 1 is an integer
element 2 is another treelist or None
element 3 is another treelist or None

ex: [1,[1,None,None],None]

example: tree = [12, [1, None, None], [3, [4, None, None], [2, None, None]]]
```

My goal is to sum all of the nodes leading up to the deepest node, and if there are multiple  nodes of the same deepest depth, then only the greatest sum (max?). I can write a function which sums up all of the nodes, but not just the specific chain which leads to the deepest node... I've been wracking my brain and can't find a solution.

I thought of one way to do it, and that was to keep track of the chain through a list containing left and right. So it would be:

```
[left,right,left]
```

which I would use to sum:

```
t[0] + t[1] + t[1][0]+ t[1][0][2] . . . and so on, but that seems overly complicated..
```

Any thoughts?

edit:
Thought of another way:
Store every combination of every possible chain as lists inside a list and use the depth function I made to only compare lists of similar length(depth) and then take the largest sum of those lists. Still I encounter the same problem though, I don't know how to grab individual chains. Also seems inefficient

Comment: This must be some sort of assignment... fourth time I've seen this question today. Although this *is* the best worded version.

Comment: If you can track the node you are at when you find the deepest node, you can then simply do a BST search for the value of that node, store the nodes you walk across during the search, and you'll get the chain to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is recursive - at each node in the tree, the answer is the value of the current node plus the value of the left or right child, depending on which is deeper (or has the greater sum, if they are of the same max depth).

```
VALUE, LEFT, RIGHT = 0, 1, 2

def get_deepest_max_sum(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0, 0
    else:
        deepest, most = max(get_deepest_max_sum(node[LEFT]), get_deepest_max_sum(node[RIGHT]))
        return 1+deepest, node[VALUE]+most

tree = [12, [1, None, None], [3, [4, None, None], [2, None, None]]]
print(get_deepest_max_sum(tree))
```

which gives

```
(3, 19)   # => depth 3, sum 19
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP needs to return the whole node traversal to that point. So need to add the additional step of doing a search to that node and storing the traversal (or the more complicated but more efficient tracking the traversal as you do the depth search).

Comment: @aruisdante: I don't think he actually _needs_ that; I think he was wondering it that is the best way to get the depth and sum, which is what he is actually after. (It's a bit hard to tell, looking at the question!).

Comment: Oh you're right, reading it again they might only need the depth/sum tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Same spirit but longer; maybe easier to understand...

```
tree = [12, [1, None, None], [3, [4, None, None], [2, None, None]]]

mx=0
depth=0

def walk(t,m=0,l=0):
    global mx, depth
    l += 1
    m += t[0]
    for b in t[1:]:
        if b:
            walk(b,m,l)
        else:
            print "level",l,"maximum",m
            if m > mx:
                mx = m
            if l > depth:
                depth = l


walk(tree)
print depth,mx
```